# What exactly gets saved when I do a "Save and Quit"?

Tags: dead-space-3

I already know that it [saves the current inventory (from its description)](https://help.ea.com/article/where-are-the-save-stations-in-dead-space-3), and although you can save and quit anywhere, it will still load at the area of the last save checkpoint.

But are there other information that is saved? Like the status of:

- items/loot lying around, dropped or otherwise (and their location)
- opened or unopened item boxes
- bodies lying around (if a limb is cut or if the body is blown to pieces, is this information also saved?)
- scavenger bots status (including location and time left before they return to a bench)
- status of rooms unlocked with Torque Bars
- which missions are currently selected and active
- suit upgrades
- ammo left in clip

Comment: I am pretty sure there was a question like this that came up a few weeks ago... but I can't find it for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically anything that would be saved if you continued playing and allowed an area to fall out of system memory:

Loose loot will despawn, as will corpses, just as if you'd kept playing without picking up the items.

Oddly, **containers, including Torque Bar locked rooms are respawned**, including all loot. This means if you're lucky enough to save before one, you can quit, reload and abuse the torque bar room (given enough torque bars of course). This is actually quite abusable in places where a bench and torque bar room are in close proximity after a save point.

Story progress isn't saved; if you save before a cutscene, you'll have to watch it again if you load that save even after seeing it once.

Scavenger bot status is saved, as are unlocked rooms and your current inventory. I'm not sure to what extent scavenger bot status is saved, but if they were searching, they'll still be searching when you resume, and the same is true if they're waiting for you at the bench; they'll still be at the bench. They aren't dumped back into your inventory or anything and you'll still get loot.

Comment: The game saves your mission-progress when "saving progress" indicator is displayed on-screen.